# What if I model a database without defining foreign keys in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, query-optimization

**Scenario 1 :** Foreign keys are defined properly

**Scenario 2 :** On Deletion and Updation of records, I can ensure that no orphaned data will be left while writing API without defining any FK. Also I will check data integrity while Insertion

So what is the difference between these two scenarios? I just want to know what benefits I will get using FK (quantitative analysis). Will I achieve better performance in Scenario - 1 than 2? I am newbie in MySQL database design.

Comment: The first solution works without having to duplicate code in different parts of your application. The second requires consistency and documentation, especially if you have multiple developers, or change developers after a time.

Comment: Will I achieve better performance in Scenario 1 than 2?

Comment: No.  Just better assurance of data integrity.

Comment: Scenario 1 may in fact perform better since it parses and optimizes a single query instead of multiple calls between the DBMS and client. For scenario 2, be sure to use transactions to prevent update inconsistencies.

Comment: Some people seem to assume they can accomplish the purpose of foreign keys in their code, inevitably to discover -- late -- that their assumptions were naïve.  Using foreign keys is the correct design.  Not using them is almost always a flawed strategy, regardless of motivation.  This isn't a real decision, and any theoretical disadvantage to using them is unimportant and entirely unworthy of consideration except in some circumstances that you are unlikely to encounter.  Use foreign keys.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thats why I just want to make sure before start designing my database whether neglecting FKs in dtabase design will cause me problems in future or not

Answer (score 1):

Performance differences...

An FK check must reach into the other table (via an index) to do the integrity check.  However...

Situation 1:  Simple FK:

In many cases, you can, via understanding the flow of the app code, assure yourself that *some* FK violations "cannot" happen.  For example, when you insert into two tables in a row (and you have checked for errors, etc), and the second table is to point to the first table's row you just inserted, then the FK test is redundant and hurts performance (a little).

If, on the other hand, you "simulate" an FK check by doing an extra `SELECT`, that would be a noticeable performance hit.

Situation 2:  FK with cascading delete:

If you use FKs for "cascading delete" (etc), then this *may* be more efficient than manually doing the delete.

Further, if you can batch the `DELETEs`, it is probably faster than letting the cascade do them one by one.

Another comment:  "Side effects", such as 'cascading' are considered (by some) to be a naughty coding practice.

But...  The above differences are *probably* not enough to make a difference in your app.

Comment: So before using FK, I should know what it does actually in the backgroud. Lets say, if I defined some FKs and I also made some transactions in the API to check data integrity, then it might cause performance issues due to redundant checks. Instead I should either do scenario 1 or 2 not both.

Comment: In a performance sense, nothing is "done in the background"; the FK action and the rest of the query are performed sequentially.  Yes, you should pick Scenario 1 or 2; my point is that the performance may be either better or worse, depending on too many factors to see at the moment.

Comment: Another note...  A FK implicitly creates an `INDEX`; with Scenario 2, be sure to manually add suitable indexes.  _Sometimes_ a composite index is better than the single-column one the FK would build.  (Another possible perf diff.)